# Cannot set the state of a unmounted component in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the react and redux. Here is, what I am doing:

I have a component which is like ,

```
class LandingPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isloading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchJobDescription().then(() => {
      this.setState({
        isloading: false
      })
    });
  }

render() {
    if (this.state.isloading) {
      return null;
    }
    else if (this.props.jobs && this.props.jobs.content && this.props.jobs.content.length > 0) {
      return <JobList />;
    }
    else if (this.props.isError) {
      return <ErrorComponent />
    }
    else {
      return <Redirect to="/create-job" />
    }
  }
}
```

the action is like ,

```
export function fetchUserJd() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    let url = FETCH_JD_ROOT_URL + page + "&" + size;
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_INITIATED
    })
    return get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          dispatch({
            type: FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS,
            data: response.payload
          })
          dispatch({
            type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
          })
        } else {
          if (!response.status) {
            toastr.error('Our server is down. Please check again');
          }
          else if (response.status.status === 401) {
            dispatch(logout());
          }
          else if (response.status.status === 500) {
            toastr.error("Error while Fetching the job description,Please try again");
            dispatch({
              type: FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS,
              data: response.status,
            });
            dispatch({
              type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
            })
          } else {
            dispatch({
              type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
            })
          }
        }
      })
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
};
```

Now,my logout is ,

```
export function logout() {
    console.log("calling the logout action");
    localStorage.clear();
    history.push('/login');
    return {
        type: LOGOUT_REQUEST
    }
}

class Header extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  logout = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logout();
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Navigation
          isAuthenticated={localStorage.getItem("access_token") ? true : false}
          operationType={this.props.operationType}
          logout={this.logout} />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.LoginReducer.isAuthenticated,
    operationType: state.Header.operationType,
  }
}
```

Here, when there is a invalid token like while fetching it gives me 401 unauthorized, then I redirect use for the logout action. now,

when I do this that time , I get an error:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in LandingPage (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Connect(LandingPage) (created by Route)
```

How I can resolve this error ?

Comment: Not much to tell, but a good point to start debugging is to `console.log` inside the `then` and in `componentDidUnMount`. If you find any `console` from `then` executing after `console` form `componentDidUnMount`, then i guess you need to fix your `fetchJobDescription` or they way your `landingpage` is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Its a small issue that happens in your code. When you receive a 401 token, you try to redirect to logout from within the action creator using history.push which will unmount your LandingPage component, but at the same time you are trying to `setState` with `loading: false`, thus you receive this warning. The solution is simple

```
class LandingPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isloading: true
    }
    this._mounted = true;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchJobDescription().then(() => {
      if (this_mounted) {
         this.setState({
           isloading: false
         }) 
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     this._mounted = false;
  }
render() {
    if (this.state.isloading) {
      return null;
    }
    else if (this.props.jobs && this.props.jobs.content && this.props.jobs.content.length > 0) {
      return <JobList />;
    }
    else if (this.props.isError) {
      return <ErrorComponent />
    }
    else {
      return <Redirect to="/create-job" />
    }
  }
}
```

or else in the action creator you can throw an error instead of dispatching the logout action and in the `.catch` block of `fetchJobDescription` dispatch the logout action

In LandingPage

```
this.props.fetchJobDescription().then(() => {
       this.setState({
           isloading: false
       }) 
    }).catch((err) => {
        this.props.logout();
    });
```

and in action creator

```
  else if (response.status.status === 401) {
        throw new Error('Error in status')
  }
```

Comment: So, Here I did this, but one of my component which is the header which does not get the updated on this. it still gets show in page. I have added the header component

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you are setting state after component has unmounted. The issue might be that you make api hit, component unmounts, Then response of api is returned which sets the state. If you are using axios it can be [handled](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation).

```
// in the component
signal = axios.CancelToken.source();
// in componentWillUnmount
this.signal.cancel('API was cancelled');
```